# Stats with Math.Net

Tags: .net, .net-core, math.net

How do you calculate the 99.5 percentile using Math.NET?

98 percentile is

```
MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Statistics.Percentile(valuesInDecile, 100 - 2)
```

99 percentile is

```
MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Statistics.Percentile(valuesInDecile, 100 - 1)
```

For a non integer p-value it says using quartile function. How should this be used as it returns NaN for

```
MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Statistics.Quantile(valuesInDecile, 100 - 0.5f)
```

My data set on which I am trying to run this:

```
0.0353737
0.0009659
0.0005655
0.0053452
0.0402773
0.0018171
0.0193516
0.0003455
0.0505242
0.0539421
0.0363619
0.0293928
0.0356062
0.0352433
0.0577016
0.0529182
0.0015018
0.0436227
0.0042247
0.0157081
0.0112555
0.0061088
0.0319852
0.020557
0.0106685
0.029806
0.0053733
0.0965764
0.0001344
0.0033052
0.0080388
0.0189088
0.024258
0.0254075
0.0852993
0.0055825
0.0712195
0.0682945
0.013282
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
MathNet.Numerics.Statistics.Statistics.Quantile(valuesInDecile, 1d - 0.005d)
```

> Instead of grouping into 4 or 100 boxes, quantiles generalize the concept to an infinite number of boxes and thus to arbitrary real numbers `tau` between 0.0 and 1.0, where 0.0 represents the minimum value, 0.5 the median and 1.0 the maximum value.
> [Quantiles | Descriptive Statistics](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/DescriptiveStatistics.html#Quantiles)

Comment: That data works fine for me: [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fOYVhU) - the `Percentile` and `Quantile` calls return the same value for 99, 99, and 100 (0.98, 0.99, 1.00); and `Quantile` for 0.95 returns `0.08107536`.